# Post JSON data from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cordova

```
app.controller("blankCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$parse', function($scope, $http, $parse) {
    $scope.login = function() {
        $scope.spice = 'tooo';
        console.log("hiii");
        alert($("#loginform").serialize()); //-------mobile=9860292514&password=123456

        //  $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/JSON'; 
        var dataObj = {
            mobile: $scope.mobile,
            password: $scope.password
        };
        $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://edudux.com/manage/index.php?/api/login',
                data:dataObj,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("status" + status); //-----------status200
                alert(angular.isObject(JSON)); // --------true            
                alert(JSON); //-------------[object JSON]

                var a = angular.toJson(dataObj);
                alert(a); //----------{}

                var b = angular.fromJson(dataObj);
                alert(b); //------------[object Object] 

                alert(data); //----------[object Object]
                alert(JSON.stringify(dataObj)); //----------{}
                console.log(JSON.stringify(dataObj));

            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert(status);
            });
    };
}]);
```

I am new to AngularJS, and developing a new application using AngularJS.
I try to post a JSON Object with AngularJS $http Server. But I get an empty object as a response : "{}"

Comment: u need to pass the data parameter hhtp request

Comment: Where are you passing your `dataObj` in $http ?

Comment: @GangadharJannu data:dataObj

Answer (score 0):

Ypu need pass the dataObj in your http request as follows.

```
app.controller("blankCtrl",['$scope','$http','$parse',function ($scope,$http,$parse) {
 $scope.login = function() {
    $scope.spice = 'tooo';
   console.log("hiii");
 alert($("#loginform").serialize()); 
//  $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
// $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/JSON'; 
var dataObj = {
            mobile : $scope.mobile,
            password : $scope.password
    };  

var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'Content-Type':'application/json;'
                }
            }

             $http.post('http://edudux.com/manage/index.php?/api/login', dataObj, config)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                alert('error');
            });

  }

}]);
```

Comment: Read [Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/)

Comment: @Naresh Kumar This code giving me error as {"Error":"mobile field is mandatory"}

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you :

```
app.controller("blankCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$parse','$q', function($scope, $http, $parse,$q) {
    $scope.login = function() {
        $scope.spice = 'tooo';
        console.log("hiii");
        alert($("#loginform").serialize()); //-------mobile=9860292516&password=123456

        //  $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/JSON'; 
        var dataObj = {
            mobile: $scope.mobile,
            password: $scope.password
        };
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url:  'http://edudux.com/manage/index.php?/api/login',
        data: dataObj,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
            console.log(deferred.promise);
            alert(data);

        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data, status, headers, config);

        });

    };
}]);
```

Comment: Read [Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/)

Comment: @Errabi Ayoub I have tried above code....I am getting response as [object Object]

Comment: Yes because i didn't know what is the response of your WS if you have for example an object in response like class A { int a;int b} ,just you have to change it to alert(data.a) ;

Comment: my web service response is {
  "Success": [
      "mobile": "9860292514",
      "password": "123456",
    }
  ]
}

Comment: you can try alert(data.mobile); or alert(data.password) this should return 9860292514 or 123456 as a value

Comment: alert(data.mobile); or alert(data.password) showing me "undefined"

Comment: try to use alert(data.Success.mobile) if it's not working then in success function add $scope.data =data ;console.log($scope.data) and see what it gives in your browser console

Comment: when i am writing  alert(data.Success.mobile) no alert is coming on screen. and when i am writing  $scope.data =data ;console.log($scope.data) in the success function it is  again giving response as [object Object]

Comment: I updated my response try this new solution hope this will work

Comment: I am getting same response as [object Object]

Comment: @ErrabiAyoub do u know any other way or method to do this??

Answer (score 0):

Shortcut method to perform `POST` request.

```
$scope.login = function () {
  // URL
  var reqURL = "http://edudux.com/manage/index.php?/api/login";

  // data
  var reqData = {
    mobile : $scope.mobile,
    password : $scope.password
  };

  $http.post(reqURL, reqData).then(function (response) {
    // response from server. after login
    console.log(response.data);
  });
};
```

Documentation: [$http request documentation.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

I hope to help you with my answer above!